# Dictionary of words separated by their length

Tags: r, list, dictionary, string-length

I have a dataframe of words like so `:chr "ABC" "ABM" "AG" "AGB" "AGP" "AD".`
I would like to convert it into a list (dictionary) of lists (of words), divided by length:

```
:chr NULL
:chr [1:2] "AD" "AG"
:chr [1:4] "ABC" "ABM" "AGB" "AGP"
```

Comment: Yes, I meant to say in R. Thanks.

Comment: Try `split(v1, nchar(v1))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split`:

```
split(words, nchar(words))  # split the words vector by the number of characters
# $`2`
# [1] "AG" "AD"

# $`3`
# [1] "ABC" "ABM" "AGB" "AGP"
```

*Data*:

```
words <- c("ABC", "ABM", "AG", "AGB", "AGP", "AD")
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the order of words? I want it lexicographic.

Comment: You can sort the result with `lapply`. `lapply(split(words, nchar(words)), sort)`.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Is there a way to have :chr NULL for when I do not have words of length 1?

Comment: You can construct a factor as group variable, i.e. `split(words, factor(nchar(words), levels = 1:max(nchar(words))))`. With that being said, a list of a NULL values for a key is the same as a list  without that key. So even for the above answer, you can query it as if it has a length `1` element and NULL value.